# Who is watching the X-Men?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers-vs-x-men

In one of the last few panels of AvX we see a figure who looks exactly like Magneto watching the scenes on Utopia, with Scott's X-Men fighting the Avengers. Who is that figure? I can only think of two people it could be but I thought both were dead: **Northstar** and **Joseph**.

Who is it?

Comment: No, no, it's "who is watching the Watchmen?" ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only panel I can think of that fits what you describe is in AvX #2:

[image]

If this is the one you're describing, that is **Quicksilver**, Magneto's son and a mutant member of the Avengers.  We see him in the following panels coming to Iron Man's aid against Magneto.

The dark figure he is talking to is later revealed to be the Scarlet Witch, his sister, by her costume when watching the same television, and the following panel containing "Wanda's Dream Journal".

Comment: I was thrown off because he looks nothing like the Quicksilver I know form the comics, but similar enough to the pictures I've seen of Northstar and Joseph. It figures they'd all look alike though.

Comment: Your question threw me because it didn't have the issue number in it, but I was able to guess what it was simply because when I read it I also scratched my head for about five minutes before I realised that the guy over the page break was meant to be the same guy.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't expecting him to enter the fray *that* quickly...

Answer (score 8):

**Northstar is not dead.** In fact there may even be two Northstar's currently existing on Earth #616. The original and a time-displaced one.

> Northstar (Jean-Paul Beaubier) is a fictional character, a superhero
>   who appears in comic books published by Marvel Comics. He is the twin
>   brother of Aurora. Through his mutation, Northstar gains superhuman
>   powers, which he uses for the betterment of society. Although
>   originally a member of Alpha Flight, a fictional team of Canadian
>   superhumans, Northstar is later portrayed as a member of the X-Men. He
>   is one of the first openly gay superheroes in American comic books. He
>   is scheduled to be the first to enter into a gay marriage, in
>   Astonishing X-Men #51, due out June 27, 2012.

**Joseph is not dead, either.** We haven't be told how he survived his death, but he returned leading a new Brotherhood of Evil mutants.

> Joseph returns at an anti-mutant rally killing all present and framing
>   Magneto. It is revealed that Joseph is the true perpetrator of the
>   crime when Erik asks Emma for help going into his mind through the
>   "magnetosphere" (similar to cerebra but using electromagnetic impulses
>   to make a map of people with his abilities). In the miniseries
>   "Magneto: Not a Hero", Joseph is resurrected under unknown
>   circumstances and forms a new Brotherhood of Mutants with Astra and
>   mutated deformed versions of Blob, Mastermind, Quicksilver, Scarlet
>   Witch, and Toad. It was soon revealed that the mutated versions of
>   Blob, Mastermind, Quicksilver, Scarlet Witch, and Toad were clones
>   created by Joseph.

As noted by dlanod and his image-clip, that is Quicksilver, son of Magneto.